# Sql Server Database values based on relation to current datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Is there a way to create a column that acts as a countdown until a certain date is reached in relation to when the value was initially added?

For instance, if the value was added today and I set the end date to be in two days, then the countdown column value would start at 2. The next day it would be at 1, and then the last day it would be at 0.

Comment: My gues: You can keep your insertion date or expiration date in the table, but not your count down. You can however create a view on your table, having a calculated column showing your count down. (If you manage to implement it, post it as an answer and earn your *self-learners* badge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a computed column for that:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id int IDENTITY,
  enddate datetime NOT NULL,
  daysleft AS (DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), enddate))
)
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/150c2/1)

Comment: Very helpful. Just to make sure, though, tomorrow all of the values in column daysleft will go down by one right?

Comment: Yes. But don't just trust me, come back tomorrow! :-) (I actually think sqlfiddle will maintain the values, so you'll see it happen.)